# BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException with EJB annotations on JBoss4

Tags: java, spring, struts2, annotations, ejb

Problem:

I'm getting the following exception when deploying my WAR files.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'campaigner-ejb/SecurityServiceImpl/remote' must be of type [com.campaigner.service.SecurityServiceRemote], but was actually of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy172]
```

I've searched SO and the rest of the web for an answer, but haven't really found one.

Background:

I'm running JBoss4 with Java5, since that's the package that I have with my hosting service. 
Later this year I may upgrade the package, but that's not a consideration right now.
I'm finally starting to use annotations after happily using XDoclet for many years.
In that regard, I'm therefore trying as much as possible to not use any XML files, though that doesn't seem possible.
I'm using Spring 3.2.13 along with Struts 2.2.3.1 (because I'm using Java5).
My project consists of multiple WAR files and an EJB JAR file. I have decided at this time not to use one EAR file to encapsulate them all.
I've read that including the CGLIB jar into my project along with adding proxy-target-class="true" into one of my XML files might solve this,
however I haven't been able to determine into which file this should go.

Here is my Java Code:

```
@Remote
public interface SecurityServiceRemote extends SecurityService
{
}


@TransactionManagement(value = TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
@Stateless
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class SecurityServiceImpl extends AbstractCampaignerServiceImpl implements
    SecurityServiceLocal, SecurityServiceRemote
{
}
```

The ServiceFactory is used by Struts2 actions. Note that I am not referencing classes here; only interfaces.

```
@Component
public class ServiceFactory
{
  private SecurityServiceRemote       securityService;

  public SecurityServiceRemote getSecurityService() throws ApplicationException
  {
    return securityService;
  }

  @EJB(name = "SecurityServiceImpl", mappedName = "campaigner-ejb/SecurityServiceImpl/remote")
  public void setSecurityService(
    SecurityServiceRemote securityService)
  {
    this.securityService = securityService;
  }
}
```

Here are the stripped-down XML files included in my EJB JAR file.

beanRefContent.xml

```
<beans>  
  <!--
    SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor needs this file.
    We need SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor to autowire the EJBs. 
   -->
  <bean
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:campaignerContext.xml" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

campaignerContext.xml

```
<beans>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.campaigner.dao.jpa,com.campaigner.service.impl" />

  <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="campaigner" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="em" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Here are the stripped-down XML files included in my WAR file.

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.campaigner.service" />
</beans>
```

struts.xml

```
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="campaigner_messages" />
  <constant name="struts.convention.action.includeJars" value=".*?/campaigner\-web.*?jar(!/)?"/>
  <constant name="struts.convention.action.fileProtocols" value="jar,zip"/>
  <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="convention-tiles"/>

  <package name="convention-tiles" extends="struts-default">
    <result-types>
      <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types>
  </package>
</struts>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>campaigner</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>campaigner_messages</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.campaigner.web.actions</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>struts.devMode</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
  </session-config>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21658566/1700321.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using a Context. Instead, the @EJB annotation seems to be handling that lookup. Also, the ServiceFactory.setSecurityService() method is already using SecurityServiceRemote as a param.